# use c++ class in objective-c

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

Basically I have 2 source files like following in my workspace:

vectormath_aos.h

```
#ifndef _VECTORMATH_AOS_CPP_SCALAR_H
#define _VECTORMATH_AOS_CPP_SCALAR_H

#include <math.h>

#ifdef _VECTORMATH_DEBUG
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

namespace Vectormath {

namespace Aos {

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward Declarations
//

class Vector3;
class Vector4;
class Point3;
class Quat;
class Matrix3;
class Matrix4;
class Transform3;
...
```

exampleopenglesViewController.mm

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "exampleopenglesViewController.h"
#import "EAGLView.h"
#import "vectormath_aos.h"

Matrix4 mvpmatrix;
...
```

However, when I try to run the project in Xcode 4.0, it always give me the error: Unknown type name "Matrix4". I am really confused because it used to work for me when I was working on Xcode 3.2. Anyone knows what goes wrong here? Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Compile Source As" property in the building target to Objective-C++?

Comment: Just tried that, and it still gives the same error, :(

Comment: oops! how could i forget about namespace! it has been a while from my last time using c++.:p, thx Bavarious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you’re using namespaces,

```
Matrix4 mvpmatrix;
```

should be:

```
Vectormath::Aos::Matrix4 mvpmatrix;
```

instead.